# Подключение стороннего web-шрифта

Tags: веб-программирование, шрифты, google-fonts

Здравствуйте.

Я использую сторонние шрифты на своём сайте. Изначально решил использовать сервис Google Fonts, однако у гугл для нужного мне шрифта отсутствует кириллица, зато на сайте разработчика шрифта кириллица уже есть.

Так вот, код подключения шрифта я взял у гугла и немного дописал. Интересуют мои ошибки, где я мог ошибиться?

Я использую четыре стиля шрифта Light, Regular, Bold, Black (300, 400, 700, 900), и мне важно, чтобы все четыре подключались через один и тот же font-family.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('lato-light.eot');
    src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'),
         url('lato-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lato-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lato-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lato-light.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('lato-regular.eot');
    src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'),
         url('lato-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lato-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lato-regular.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('lato-bold.eot');
    src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), 
         url('lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lato-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lato-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lato-bold.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url('lato-black.eot');
    src: local('Lato Black'), local('Lato-Black'),
         url('lato-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lato-black.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lato-black.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lato-black.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Comment: Так в чём собственно вопрос? В чём проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что ошибка есть, код работает не совсем так, как должен, по крайней мере при использовании гугла проблем с использованием 4 стилей шрифта не было, а теперь есть, видимо использование одного и того же font-family требует ещё каких то деталей, возможно, в файлах самих шрифтов.

Comment: >код работает не совсем так, как должен
Как должен, как работает?

Comment: Всё, я уже сам решил проблему, похоже, я где-то ошибся с символами просто у себя в css, переписал по новой код, и всё встало на свои места)